# Trigger on EmailTempAttachmentMap

Tags: trigger, email

Has anybody written a trigger on the EmailTempAttachmentMap object type.

I am not sure how to access that ObjectType.

thanks.

Comment: Goal is to prevent attachment of a certain type while attaching a file in an email in a Contact Related List.  if you add an attachment to an Email in a related list. and then click on preview , the Object prefix starts with '0F0' which is the prefix of object type EmailTempAttachmentMap. i want to check on this object type, whether the attachment has type .xls or .csv and then throw some sort of validation error. However, currently, i am not able to find that object type. is there a new object type referring to prefix code '0F0'

Answer (score 1):

It seems that particular object type has been deprecated, API does not list it, and every reference to that object type while searching is few years ago. Are you sure that this is the object you need to create trigger on?

Comment: if you add an attachment to an Email in a related list. and then click on preview , the Object prefix starts with '0F0' which the prefix of object type EmailTempAttachmentMap. i want to check on this object type, whether the attachment has type .xls or .csv and then throw some sort of validation error. However, currently, i am not able to find that objecttype. is there a new object type referring to prefix code '0F0'.